# .NET Core 2.0 MVC file upload progress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-blob-storage

So I've had a hell of a time trying to display a progress bar for my .Net Core MVC app and the official documentation has not been very helpful.

Docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.0#uploading-large-files-with-streaming

I also want to upload the file to Azure blob storage when it gets to my controllers.
The user can upload as many files as they like.

Here is my code for uploading:

```
for (int i = 0; i < videoFile.Count; i++)
            {

                long totalBytes = videoFile[i].Length;

                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                using (Stream input = videoFile[i].OpenReadStream())
                {
                    long totalReadBytes = 0;
                    int readBytes;

                    while ((readBytes = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        totalReadBytes += readBytes;
                        var progress = (int)((float)totalReadBytes / (float)totalBytes * 100.0);
                    }
                }

                String videoPath = videoFile[i].FileName;

                await sc.UploadBlobAsync(groupContainer, videoPath, videoFile[i]);
            }
```

And here is my UploadBlobAsync method:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadBlobAsync(string blobContainer, string blobName, IFormFile file) {
        CloudBlobContainer container = await GetContainerAsync(blobContainer);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
        IProgress<StorageProgress> progressHandler = new Progress<StorageProgress>(
            progress => Console.WriteLine("Progress: {0} bytes transferred", progress.BytesTransferred)
        );

        using (var filestream = file.OpenReadStream()) {
            await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(filestream,
                default(AccessCondition),
                default(BlobRequestOptions),
                default(OperationContext),
                progressHandler,
                cancellationToken);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

What I'd want to know is:

1. To my understanding, I would have to do 2 progress bars, 1 for the client machine to my server, than another from my server to azure. Is this correct?
2. How do I display the progress for each of my files to the frontend? I'd imagine it would be an ajax request to a List[i] I set up in my Controller?
3. Am I reading the bytes in the while loop when the file is already buffered? If I can access the file stream, isn't the file already buffered on the server?
4. How can I make use of Azure's IProgress implementation to return the result to me when it changes? Console.Writeline does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

From another angle, you should try using the checking mechanism of a blob upload 
 progress, a sample is bellow:

```
 var speedSummary = blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream('mycontainer', file.name, fileStream, file.size, function(error, result, response) {...}

setTimeout(function() {
    if (!finishedOrError) {
        var process = speedSummary.getCompletePercent();
        displayProcess(process);
        refreshProgress();
    }
}, 200);
```

You can find more details here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/310

1- You can only use one progress bar

2-  You could use the progress mechanism recently published in github based on a blob upload.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, you need to provide a StorageProgress instance to your handler before calling UploadFromStreamAsync:

```
long byteLength = 1048576L; // 1MB at time
StorageProgress storageProgress = new StorageProgress(byteLength);
progressHandler.Report(storageProgress);
```